# Why does my program think 4 is a prime number?

Tags: java, algorithm

Any idea why this method returns true for '4'?

```
private boolean isPrime(int num) {
            if (num < 2) {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 2; i < num / 2; i++) {
                if (num % i == 0)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
}
```

Comment: I am sure your debugger could help you debug your program. If you don't know how to use your debugger, I suggest you learn.

Comment: BTW, a more efficient approach is to do `for (int i = 2, max = (int) Math.sqrt(num); i <= max; i++)` You can improve this further by only checking odd numbers after checking `2` as a factor.

Comment: always prefer debugging in such cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It returns true since your loop starts from `2` and ends in `num / 2 -1` which in the case of `num = 4` is `1`. That means you never enter the for loop.

Your `for` loop should be

```
for (int i = 2; i <= num/2; i++)
```

Note that the running time of your loop would be `O(num)`. For more efficiency you might want to consider the loop

```
for (int i = 2; i * i <= num; i++)
```

which is `O(sqrt(num))`.

Answer (score 3):

A more efficient solution is to check for 2 followed by odd numbers up to the sqrt(n) as any number above this would have to mean there is a factor less than this.

```
static boolean isPrime(long num) {
    if (num < 2) return false;
    if (num == 2) return true;
    if ((num & 1) == 0) return false; // must be even
    for (int i = 3, max = (int) Math.sqrt(num); i <= max; i += 2)
        if (num % i == 0) 
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What does this return when you pass it `2`?

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thank you. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

It is returning `true` because control never got inside of `for` loop.

```
for(int i = 2; i < num / 2; i++) { ... }
```

here `num` was `4` then `num / 2` will be `2`

```
for(int i = 2; i < 2; i++) { ... }
```

And initially i is 2 which is not less than 2. So `i < 2` will give false.
So your loop never run. and function will return `true`